# Android: How to get the contact id by the phone number?

Tags: android, contacts, phone-number

I need to do it in Android (API 1.6)doughnut

Comment: if you know of so many could you post a link to one then?

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=how+to+get+contact+id+by+phone+number#hl=en&sa=X&ei=6KsITvfkIoPfgQeR6OjrDQ&ved=0CBYQvwUoAQ&q=how+to+get+contact+id+by+phone+number+android&spell=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=3decf20ad3dbe1ab&biw=1050&bih=1079

Answer (score 23):

try this piece of code, worked fine for me...

```
ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();

Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phoneNumber));

String[] projection = new String[] {ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.PhoneLookup._ID};

Cursor cursor =  
   contentResolver.query(
        uri, 
        projection, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null);

if(cursor!=null) {
  while(cursor.moveToNext()){
    String contactName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME));
    String contactId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup._ID));
    Log.d(LOGTAG, "contactMatch name: " + contactName);
    Log.d(LOGTAG, "contactMatch id: " + contactId);
  }
  cursor.close();
}
```

Comment: Even though the code is technically correct, it can leave your cursor unclosed.

Comment: @zegnus can use finally!